# Dynamically adding vue components

Tags: vue.js

pls, am trying to add some components dynamically in vue so that i can easily create some tabs, the components are all stored in an array, but when i looped through each of those components, it displayed the name of the components instead of the content of the components, below is my code

```html
<template>
    <v-card>
       <v-tabs color="#4FC3F7"  slider-color="#004D40" right grow>
            <v-tab ripple v-for="(ttab, index) in tabss" :key="index">{{ttab}}</v-tab>
            <v-tab-item v-for="(tabCont, index) in tabConts" :key="index">
                {{tabCont}}
            </v-tab-item>  
            </v-tabs>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
  import ProfileComponents from './Profile.vue' 
  import PasswordsComponents from './Passwords.vue' 
  import ProjectsComponents from './Projects.vue' 
  import FiniancialsComponents from './Finiancials.vue' 
  import VerificationsComponents from './Verifications.vue'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tabss:['Profile','Passwords','Projects','Finiancials','Verifications'
                ],
                tabConts:['<ProfileComponents/>','<PasswordsComponents/>','<ProjectsComponents/>','<FiniancialsComponents/>','<VerificationsComponents/>'
                ],
            };
        },
        components:{
            ProfileComponents, PasswordsComponents, ProjectsComponents, FiniancialsComponents, VerificationsComponents
        }
    }
</script>
```

pls what am i doing wrong

Comment: You are using the `tabCont` as a string. Use it as html.
`v-html="tabCont"`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, tabConts is just an array of strings, so you're getting what you are asking for.

You probably want to use the 'component' component, which lets you specify the name of the component to insert as a property:

```
<component v-bind:is="componentName"></component>
```

So your template changes to something like this:

```
<template>
    <v-card>
       <v-tabs color="#4FC3F7"  slider-color="#004D40" right grow>
            <v-tab ripple v-for="(ttab, index) in tabss" :key="index">{{ttab}}</v-tab>
            <v-tab-item v-for="(tabCont, index) in tabConts" :key="index">
                <component :is="tabCont"></component>
            </v-tab-item>  
            </v-tabs>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

This assumes the components are registering themselves correctly, etc., but this should get you closer to a solution.